# File folders with foreign names

Tags: windows, windows-vista, restore

I have Windows Vista.  When I open my document file there are file folders with names that look chinese.  Do not know where they came from.  Any ideas?  I have Avast virus program.

In addition to that my restore does not work.  I can create a restore point but then once the computer is restarted it is not there.Is there anyway I might find those files without going through the Windows Restore?

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely a virus. Reinstall windows and BEFORE OPENING any drives install latest antivirus and scan every drive. The best thing will be to download latest version of kaspersky or norton. You can always download 60 days trial from them.